# modifying config file while installing with installshield 2011

Tags: installation, configuration-files, installshield

I have to modify a config file while installing with user inputs and I'm using the installshield 2011 basic msi project. I guess this can be done with xml file changes so I created a dialog with edit fields for these user inputs and associated the fields to properties but it's not clear how to associate the properties with values in my config. What is the way to do this?? This is the structure of my config file:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Color" value=""></add>
        <add key="Shape" value=""></add>
    </appSettings>
<configuration>
```

The user has to set values for color and shape. Maybe, is it better to use other kind of project?? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I always use text file changes, and set up the config file as follows

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Color" value="">%color%</add>
        <add key="Shape" value="">%shape%</add>
    </appSettings>
<configuration>
```

Then set the text replace to search for *.config 
and replace the text %color% and %shape% with the input from your dialog box.

Hope this helps

Comment: I highly discourage anyone from doing find/replace in xml files.  It's very brittle.  If the file in the example is updated to have %color% or %shape% for a different node such as <clientSettings>, things will bet more complicated.

Comment: Installshield doesn't make this process easy, and this may be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

InstallShield XML changes uses XPath statements.  It takes a little while to get used to so try something like this.

In XML File Changes, select XML Files and right click New File.  On the general table you select the directory and file name that you want to manipulate and the feature(s) being installed that cause the change to occur.

Right click the XML file and select Add Predefined Element | .NET Configuration Files | Web Configuration File | Application Settings | Add.

You'll see InstallShield authored a query of:

/configuration/appSettings/add[@key="key" and @value="value"]

This tells MSI to get a reference to the add node that is a child of the appSettings node which is a child of the configuration node where the key attribute equals the literal of "key" and the value attribute equals the literal of "value".   You'll actually want to tweak this XPath statement to compare based on the @Key="Color" and ignore the value attribute.   Once it has a reference to this node you can tell it to create/set the value of the "value" attribute to the contents of your property.  Remember that in MSI the [] symbols return the value of the specified property. ( [SOMEPROP] would return the value of SOMEPROP ).

Here's some reading material:

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield14helplib/XMLFileChangesView.htm

If all of this XML stuff is too hard for you,  recent versions of InstallShield also have a Text File Changes which can be done the way SteveLovell has mentioned.